# Two identities of sums and integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I'd like to know how to show the following identities.
$$ \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(4n+1)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{1+x^4}dx, $$ and
$$ \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(4n+3)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2\log x}{1+x^4}dx. $$
I tried to prove this but I was unsuccessful. I started with the series of $\log x$ and then obtained something like
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{1+(xy)^2}dxdy. $$

Comment: May you show your attempts, please?

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac1{1+x^4} = 1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+\cdots$.

Comment: Expanding on Greg's hint, try to make it look like the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $|y|<1$, $ \displaystyle  \frac{1}{1+y}=\sum_{n \geqslant 0}(-1)^n y^n$. Replacing y by $ x^4$ yields
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^4}=\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n x^{4 n} \Rightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4} d x=\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n  \underbrace{ \int_0^1 x^{4 n} \ln x }_{J} d x
$$
Let $\frac{y}{4 n+1}=-\ln x$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
J
& =-\frac{1}{(4 n+1)^2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} y d y \\
& =-\frac{1}{(4 n+1)^2} \Gamma(1) \\
& =-\frac{1}{(4 n+1)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence $$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^4} d x=\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(4 n+1)^2}}
$$

---

Similarly,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2 \ln x}{1+x^4} d x=\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^n \int_0^1 x^{4 n+2} \ln x d x
$$

Let $\frac{y}{4 n+3}=-\ln x$, then $$
J=-\frac{1}{(4 n+3)^2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} y d y=-\frac{1}{(4 n+3)^2}
$$
Hence
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{x^2\ln x}{1+x^4} d x=\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(4 n+1)^3}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\log x=\frac {d}{ds}x^s|_{s=0}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{4n}=\frac{1}{1+x^4}$.